# regex issue with finding " a-Z , a-Z "

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I am looking to find comma after Oliver and before Roy in the following string

```
"Username,Hello Person Oli,"Oliver,Who" roy,Roy"
```

I want to replace this one `Oliver,Who`

I am using the following regex

```
'/^"(?:[a-zA-Z]+)(?:,+)(?:[a-zA-Z]+)"$/'
```

However its not working with preg_replace

This is my code

```
$pregData   = preg_replace('/^"(?:[a-zA-Z]+)(?:,+)(?:[a-zA-Z]+)"$/',';',$csv);
```

Any ideas why ?

Sorry for the poor first message.

Comment: Between Oliver and Roy there are two commas, which one do you want to find? or is it both?

Comment: Please, improve your question.

Comment: Show your code. What is not working? What is the replacement, what the expected result? Why are those two commas different from the first two commas, that you don't want to replace?

Comment: What if its another string such as "Dave Barry,Scot Jones"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To take into account other characters than just `a-z`, you could use:

```
/"([^,]+?),(.+?)"/
```

- `"` = quote
- `[^,]+?,` = anything that's not a comma until the first comma
- `.+?"` = anything else until the next quote

Note that the string on the left and on the right of the comma are captured by `(...)` constructs. That means that, if the expression matches, then the string on the left will be assigned to `\1`, while the string on the right will be assigned to `\2`. Therefore, if you want to replace this with something like `left; right`, you could use:

```
preg_replace('/"([^,]+?),(.+?)"/', '\1; \2', $csv)
```

If you just want to keep the left and right parts without the comma in the middle, you can simply replace the expression with the left part, followed by a space, followed by the right part.

```
preg_replace('/"([^,]+?),(.+?)"/', '\1 \2', $csv)
```

Comment: That worked however when I am using preg_replace is possible to keep the string before and after the comma ? it worked however I lost the string before and after  e.g "Username,Hello Person Oli,; roy,Roy" is what im left with now

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is looking for a text with only `a-z` at the beginning, a comma, and `a-z` again. That doesn't match with your string, you should remove the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of string characters.

```
/"(?:[a-zA-Z]+)(?:,+)(?:[a-zA-Z]+)"/
```

Comment: Using preg_replace is possible to keep the string before and after the comma ? it worked however I lost the string before and after

Comment: e.g  "Username,Hello Person Oli,; roy,Roy" is what im left with now

Comment: @OliverBS see my answer, you need to make two of your groups to capturing groups.

Comment: @SeRPRo what would I do if I wanted to just remove the comma and keep the string before and after ?

Comment: @OliverBS just this: preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z]+)(?:,+)([a-zA-Z]+)"/', '\1\2', $yourString, -1, $count);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only the comma, then you need, additionally to the two wrong anchors, to make the outer groups capturing.

```
'/"([a-zA-Z]+)(?:,+)([a-zA-Z]+)"/'
```

So that you can reuse the captured words around the comma using `$1` and `$2`

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v5aj)